# Nginx pass parameter in uri if exists

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

In my nginx config file, I have a location directive:

```
    location /service1/ {
        rewrite ^\/service1\/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://internal-service1;
    }
```

I have 2 scenarios:

1. hitting the end-point http://example/service1 should show me content of http://internal-service1/    (i.e. the home page)
2. Hitting the end-point http://example/service1/someID should show me contect of http://internal-service1/someID (specific details of someID)

However, in the 1st scenario, it is still hitting  http://internal-service1/someID with 'someID' as empty and so I see the page of http://internal-service1/someID with someID as an empty string.

I think I am missing something very obvious here. But not able to figure it out.

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Is `service1` a location or a domain name? It appears as a `location` in your configuration, but as a domain name in your examples.

Comment: service1 is a location. I have corrected it now. Thanks!

Comment: What does `http://service1/someID with 'someID' as empty` mean?

Comment: If http://internal-service1/A1234 renders a page with the content:
id = A1234,
'someID' as empty means http://internal-service1/ renders a page with the content:
id =

Comment: Ok, but isn't *`http://internal-service1/someID` with 'someID' as empty* the same as *`http://internal-service1/`*? I am not sure how your two scenarios are different.

Comment: http://internal-service1 and http://internal-service1/someID should show me 2 separate pages. This is not happening. I see the same page (the one for http://internal-service1/someID) for both endpoints.

Comment: You are correct that http://internal-service1/someID with 'someID' as empty is the same as http://internal-service1/. But the parameter 'someID' should not even exist for http://internal-service1/

Comment: In my react app I then have this:
  <Route path="/:someID" component={IDPage}/>
  <Route path="/" component={homePage}/>
But both urls only redirect to IDPage. So I assumend that somehow nginx is passing :someID as empty and so I see the IDPage only in both scenarios